# Update table using form with field from another table

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have two tables one `tblEmployee` and another `tblCity`.

The two tables are setup like this:

```
tblEmployee   
-------------
employeeID       
cityID                
name
sex
contactNo

tblCity
-------------
cityID
cityName
```

I would like to create a form whereby an admin can update an employee's details. The form has a drop down box which is populated by the `cityName`s in `tblCity`.

I am struggling coming up with a query to allow the admin to select one of these cities from the drop down which will update the employee's `cityID` to the corresponding city in `tblCity`.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: What does phpMyAdmin have to do with this? Are trying to setup the form within that software?

Comment: Sorry, in hindsight, phpMyAdmin doesn't necessarily relate to this.

Comment: I suspect what you want is to setup the select values like this: `<option value="cityID">cityName</option>` The `cityID` will be submitted, and then you put that value in the `tblEmployee.cityID`. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/5McA9/

Comment: This will show the difference (you need a console open, such as Firebug or Chrome console): http://jsfiddle.net/5McA9/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect what you want is to setup the select values like this:

```
<option value="cityID">cityName</option>
```

The `cityID` will be submitted, and then you put that value in the `tblEmployee.cityID`.

For example:

```
<p>
    <select id="sel1">
        <option value="001">Auburn</option>
        <option value="002">Austin</option>
        <option value="003" selected>Dallas</option>
        <option value="004">Houston</option>
    </select>
    <button rel="sel1">Show selected value (with value attribute)</button>
</p>
<p>
    <select id="sel2">
        <option>Auburn</option>
        <option>Austin</option>
        <option selected>Dallas</option>
        <option>Houston</option>
    </select>
    <button rel="sel2">Show selected value (no value attribute)</button>
</p>

$('button').click(function(){
    var $sel = $('#' + $(this).attr('rel')).find('option:selected');
    console.log($sel.val() + ' - ' + $sel.text());
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5McA9/1/